# Xcode Project cannot build after adding iOS Charts Framework (Info.plist not found)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, info.plist, ios-charts

I recently added the iOS-Charts framework to my Xcode Project. The project would build before I added the framework to my project, but will not afterwards. I am not even using any of the framework's features yet, it is not imported anywhere, I have just added it in embedded binaries according to the instructions [here](https://github.com/danielgindi/ios-charts/blob/master/README.md).

The build fail message: `could not read data from .../AppName/Supporting Files/Info.plist': The file "Info.plist" couldn't be opened because there is no such file.`

This does not make sense because nothing has been moved and if I remove the framework from the embedded binaries section the project does build.

Help will be much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Have you tried to do a clean ?

Comment: Yes the clean succeeds with no issues but the build still fails.

Comment: I've used several weeks ago this framework (added as an embedded binary), but didn't get any errors

Comment: But the Info.plist file is still in your project and also named so?

Comment: Yes, that wasn't changed

Answer (score 0):

The error message has said clearly: `The file "Info.plist" couldn't be opened because there is no such file.` When you see this, double check the Info.plist file in your disk, to make sure it does exists.

If you removed the library and it start building again, it's more like the Info.plist is modified but broken. You may want to google and do some testing, like creating a new project and import the library to give a try. If the new project has the same issue, file an issue on its github page.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the project file for iOS Charts was moved when I was setting it up. The project file had to be dragged into the Xcode interface, not actually moved into the project directory.

Answer (score 0):

I have met the same problem with you, as it said "no such file", and it provides the path of it. So I realized that I forget to copy "Supporting Files" to folder.

Notice the file in this screenshot:
[the missing Info.plist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5x5Ra.jpg)

Then in your project: TARGET -> Building Settings -> Packaging -> Info.plist File

By the way, due to the bug of Xcode, you should build before import Charts.

Good Luck!